# Is the Innsbruck to Prague sleeper train really direct?

Tags: trains, prague, innsbruck

I am planning to book a direct sleeper train from Innsbruck to Prague through [České Dráhy/Czech Railways](https://www.cd.cz/en/default.htm). The train page says:

> Depart from Innsbruck Hbf 
>   (Train name: **EN 467 EN Night Jet** /EN 463/**S 1540**) to Praha hl.

Why are there so many names of this train or am I wrong to assume that this is a direct train? The train name changes from Salzburg Hbf (dep. 3:50) to train no. **EN 463** and from station Linz Hbf (dep. 6:35) to **Train S 1540**.

Does this mean I would be required to change trains at Salzburg and at Linz?

Comment: I believe it's the same physical train that changes its number along its route.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The important part first: You can stay in your compartment - and to be safe, you should stay there during the stop in Salzburg.

This train consists of so-called "Kurswagen" - the individual cars go on different routes. In Salzburg cars get changed between trains. According to the schedule for early June: There is one train coming from Zurich via Innsbruck to Salzburg. This one gets split up into a part going to Budapest (EN 40467) and a part going to Vienna (NJ 467) as well as your train (EN 50467) to Praha.

Additionally, there is one train arriving from Munich (EN 463) that gets coupled to (EN 40467) and travels as one unit to Budapest.

For the sleeper cars, you will have a reservation and this one will be in the right car. So, remember which car is yours or you might have to explore the beautiful city of Vienna instead of the equally beautiful Praha the next morning. On the other hand, at 3 a.m. you should be sleeping.

The name change to S 1540 is probably due to the fact that the train is operated by the Czech railway from Linz on. This means that train crew changes and sometimes the engine is changed as well.

Comment: Yes!  In Europe you must check not only that you are getting on the right TRAIN but also on the right CAR.  Each car has a destination sign.  Double check before settling in!

Comment: This reminds me when I was on the “Romulus” train (Rome-Vienna). At Venice Mestre a couple of cars were detached to go on to Venice S. Lucia (center of Venice) and others from S. Lucia were coupled. A guy in my compartment was startled realizing the train had changed direction when leaving: he was aimed to Venice. “Wrong car, sorry”. First stop: Pordenone (about 100km).